# The sequence $a(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n \varphi(k)$ has much primes, as expected

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

The sequence

> $$a(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n \varphi(k)$$

has, in the range $2 \leq n\leq 10$ a total of $5$ primes.

It has $36$ primes in the range $2 \leq n\leq 100$.

$203$ primes in the range $2 \leq n\leq 1000$ and, $1348$ primes in the range $2 \leq n\leq 10000$.

As expected, primes are becoming less dense, but, there is still much of them.

> Are there any properties of totient function that guarantee us an infinite number of primes in this sequence?

It is known that $\varphi(n)$ is even for $n \geq 3$.

This is really hard (as noted in the comment) and the methods may be still unavailable, I even do not know how to heuristically justify this.

Comment: I don't we're anywhere near providing an answer to that question.

Comment: @Klangen There are many known properties of totient, I am not sure that they cannot be combined so to yield an answer.

Comment: Upto $n=10^8$ , we have $5969900$ primes, so about $6$% of all $n$ give a prime, which is much in such ranges.

Comment: This is an efficient routine to count the primes : ? q=0;s=0;n=1;while(n<10^8,n=n+1;s=s+eulerphi(n);if(ispseudoprime(s)==1,q=q+1));
print(q)

Comment: Maybe, we can use some properties to show that the sum has a good chance to be prime. However, usually it is not possible to prove that any non-trivial sequence contains infinite many primes. The only non-trivial case which has been solved (assuming a univariate function $f(n)$ ) is the linear case solved by Dirichlet.

Comment: Maybe, it is worth noting that it has been proven that $$a^2+b^4$$ with integers $a$ and $b$ produces infinite many primes.

Comment: sieve of sundaram. note which ones can change it from 1 mod 6.